# Resizing header logo when scrolling on a Twitter Bootstrap page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am having my first go at designing a site using Twitter Bootstrap and could use some advice on resizing my logo as the page is scrolled down. See a working example here - http://opheliadesign.com/index_dev.php

First, here is the HTML for the navbar where the logo is located:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="/index_dev.php" class="brand"></a><img src="img/logo-dark-small.png"  alt="Ophelia Design" style="float:left; margin: 5px;"/>
                    <ul class="nav" style="float: right;">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the CSS...

```
body {
          padding-top: 120px;
          padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
        div.navbar-inner {
            background: #282828 !important;
        }
        #header {
            overflow: auto;
            background: #a99472;
            padding: 4px;
            border-radius:4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        }
        #header small {
            color: #334B2A;
        }
```

And finally, the jQuery I am using to resize the logo -

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrolled > 48) {
        $("#logo").css({'height': '68px'});
    } else {
        $("#logo").css({'height' : '108px'});
    }
})
```

My question - is there a better way to implement this? Especially one that would be more fitting for my responsive Bootstrap design? Also, thoughts on resizing with css vs loading another img by changing its `src` attribute would be appreciated.